# AJAX Not Hitting complete, success, or error on JSONP Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

There is a block of pre-existing code that does not appear to be working (but I am told it once did). I have simplified it into a short AJAX request (below).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://{myJspUrl}/page.jsonp",
    data: {
        param1: '${myJspParam}',
        param2: 'hardcodedParam1',
        param3: 'hardcodedParam2',
        param4: ''
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    complete: function() { alert("Complete"); },
    success: function(singleReturn) { alert("Success"); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error"); }
});
```

No alerts are produced with this code.

I tried removing the `data` parameter and updating the `url` parameter to  `https://{myJspUrl}/page.jsonp?param1=${myJspParam}&param2=hardcodedParam1&param3=hardcodedParam2&param4=` but this yielded the same results.

However, if I `alert` the above URL and go to it in a browser, the jsonp file is downloaded without error.

If I change the `dataType` to `json`, the success and complete functions are hit, but I get the following message.

[image]

Is there any way I can get the AJAX to work without seeing the security warning? **NOTE** - I cannot change browsers or affect the browser's security level (these are controlled via the company).

Comment: Is `{myJspUrl}` the same domain that the page with this ajax snippet is on?

Comment: F12, are any errors occurring when you request it with jsonp and get no result? According to the documentation: *"Note: [the error] handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests."* the error will instead be in the browser's console.

Comment: My suspicion is that you don't actually have JSONP, you instead have JSON.

Comment: You may need to use `$.getJSON` [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) as it sounds like this could be cross-domain data. such as `$.getJson("https://{myJspUrl}/page.jsonp", function(data){});

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that's essentially identical to what he currently has. getJSON will be turned into $.ajax with dataType: jsonp for cross-domain requests.

Comment: @War10ck - Not for my current setup. I am running localhost for the ajax containing app and pulling from a development server for the ajax URL.

Comment: @KevinB - no errors at all with the JSONP. Just nothingness.

Comment: Could you test this in a browser with a better console to see if you actually see useful errors? Preferably one with a network tab (anything newer than IE8)

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - The switch to `$.getJSON` did not work.

Comment: @KevinB - I have Firefox available. There are no alerts there either.

Comment: Open console and look at the network tab. Is the request sent? what does the response contain?

Comment: 302 Found, 0 KB of text/html